# How do I convert number to string and pass it as argument to Execute Process Task?

Tags: ssis

I am using *Execute Process* task in SSIS 2008 R2. I have a variable `idVar` which is of data type *Int32*. I need to pass this variable to property `Arguments` of the task so the process executable can take this variable as argument. I use expression to assign `@idVar` to `Arguments`.

Now the system says I need to convert Int to String so I used the following expression in the expression builder

```
(DT_STR, 10, 1252) @[User::IdVar]
```

It gives the following error:

```
Expression cannot be evaluated.

Additional information:
The expression "(DT_STR, 10, 1252) @[User:IdVar]" has a result type of "DT_STR", 
which cannot be converted to a supported type.

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls)
```

What is the correct way to type cast the number to string?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### Cause of the issue:

*`Arguments`* property in *Execute Process Task* available on the *Control Flow* tab is expecting a value of data type `DT_WSTR` and not `DT_STR`.

#### SSIS 2008 R2 package illustrating the issue and fix:

Create an SSIS package in *Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) 2008 R2* and name it as *`SO_13177007.dtsx`*. Create a package variable with the following information.

```
Name   Scope        Data Type  Value
------ ------------ ---------- -----
IdVar  SO_13177007  Int32      123
```

[image: Variables pane]

Drag and drop an *Execute Process Task* onto the *Control Flow* tab and name it as *Pass arguments*

[image: Control Flow tab]

Double-click the *Execute Process Task* to open the *`Execute Process Task Editor`*. Click *Expressions* page and then click the *Ellipsis* button against the *Expressions* property to view the *`Property Expression Editor`*.

[image: Execute Process Task Editor]

On the *Property Expression Editor*, select the property *`Arguments`* and click the *Ellipsis* button against the property to open the *`Expression Builder`*.

[image: Property Expression Editor]

On the *Expression Builder*, enter the following expression and click *`Evaluate Expression`*. This expression tries to convert the integer value in the variable *`IdVar`* to string data type.

```
(DT_STR, 10, 1252) @[User::IdVar]
```

[image: Expression Builder - DT_STR]

Clicking *Evaluate Expression* will display the following error message because the Arguments property on *Execute Process Task* expects a value of data type *`DT_WSTR`*.

[image: Integer to ANSI string conversion error]

To fix the issue, update the expression as shown below to convert the integer value to data type *`DT_WSTR`*. Clicking *Evaluate Expression* will display the value in the *Evaluated value* text area.

```
(DT_WSTR, 10) @[User::IdVar]
```

[image: Expression Builder - DT_WSTR]

#### References:

To understand the differences between the data types *`DT_STR`* and *`DT_WSTR`* in SSIS, read the documentation [*Integration Services Data Types*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx) on MSDN. Here are the quotes from the documentation about these two string data types.

#### DT_STR

A null-terminated ANSI/MBCS character string with a maximum length of 8000 characters. (If a column value contains additional null terminators, the string will be truncated at the occurrence of the first null.)

#### DT_WSTR

A null-terminated Unicode character string with a maximum length of 4000 characters. (If a column value contains additional null terminators, the string will be truncated at the occurrence of the first null.)

Answer (score 6):

Expression:

```
"Total Count: " + (DT_WSTR, 11)@[User::int32Value]
```

For reference, Int 32's range is (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647). Including the - sign for negatives, that makes up to 11 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Expression:
"Total Count: " + (DT_WSTR, 5)@[User::Cnt]